# decimals from given range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to write sql query (in mssql), that returns decimals from given range (each in seperate row)?
e.g.

```
11
12
13
14
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Itzik Ben-Gan's technique](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-of-numbers.aspx) (this will get you numbers up to 4,294,967,296) for producing a numbers table:

```
WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
SELECT n FROM Nums WHERE n between 11 and 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want

```
declare @start int=11;
declare @end int=26;

with cte as(
select @start as col union all
select COL+1 from cte where col+1<=@end)

select * from cte
```